# Netsuite Rest API i can't retriving any shipping details (status etc.) of sales order

Tags: netsuite-rest-api

i'm trying to get shipping details of sales order but i was't success in this task can you help me guys

i was tried 2 APIs for that (following method was used) but could not retrive any response from this APIs indicate me or Help me what will do.
GET /record/v1/transaction
?q=type:SalesOrder AND shippingStatusChanged:true AND lastModifiedDate>2022-01-01T00:00:00Z
&fields=tranId,shippingStatus,otherFields

GET /record/v1/salesOrder
?q=shippingStatusChanged:true AND lastModifiedDate>2022-01-01T00:00:00Z&fieldExp=tranId,shippingStatus,otherFields